# Redux structure calling multiple resources

Tags: reactjs, rest, redux

So I have web-application built with react and redux that is talking with a rest api built with express.js and mongodb.
I want to build a profile page, that will show latest images for that profile and latest comments.

Every image have reference to comments and user, every comment have reference to image and user.

So I could for example do get images?userid=949943 and get all the data back that I need, but as I understand in redux it's recommended to store the data flat.

so in the store it would probably be like

```
{
 images: {},
 comments: {},
 users: {}
}
```

Should I then do 3 different api requests?

get user/949943

get images?userid=949943

get comments?userid=949943

Where do I bind everything together? I have action files for users, comments and images. Should I then create a new action file that import all those actions and call those 3 actions from there? I find it difficult how to structure with redux when multiple resources is being used, most of the tutorials gives examples with only 1 resource.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr).

If you can feel comfortable setting up the schema required then you can take the response from your API from a single endpoint and populate your Redux store using the flat structure you mentioned, catering for multiple data models.